# Can't see vertices, edges or faces in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, faces

I was working just fine and suddenly when I changed from object to *Edit Mode*, neither vertices, edges nor faces were highlighted as usual.

I can still select them but can't see them, the object is displayed as in object mode. It happens with all my objects in the scene. Does anybody know why this could happen? I'm using 2.8

[image]

This is my viewport. I have one edge selected

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing please?

Comment: I posted it in an answer to the original post, I didn't know if I could answer just to you, I'm kinda new...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. You should include the image as part of your question. To edit your question, click the "edit" button at the bottom left of your question. (only answers should be posted as answers.) Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know I could do that, sorry!

Comment: It's alright, thank you! The problem could be a modifier (solidify, perhaps?). Do you have any modifiers set up?

Comment: No :( It happens with all my objects (they are hidden in the snapshot) and I've just realize that when I go to object mode and select the objects in the outliner they are not even highlighted in orange in the viewport, I can move, rotate and scale them but can't see the selection

Comment: To add to this, in my case somehow the "solidify" modifier caused the problem. I changed the "offset" parameter and suddenly the vertices appeared again.

Comment: Watch this video. I spent 3 hours trying to figure out the same. After you add a modifier it has to also be applied afterwards for it to work. After adding the modifier enter object mode. Go to each modifier and use the dropdown arrow next to the camera icon and select "apply" then when you go back into edit mode you should see the vert points: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUbg-V_vRM0&ab_channel=TheCGEssentials

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that OVERLAYS is turned off, this feature is added in Blender 2.8, press the icon that looks like two intersecting circles next to Overlays.
[image]

In your image, it appears at the bottom of the 3D Viewport, by default it's at the top.

Comment: omg thanks! I've been stuck for half an hour

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

I just had this same problem, but *Overlays* was turned on. The problem was that in the *Subsurface* modifier the *Optimal Display* box was checked. I unchecked it and the mesh appeared instantly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to click on the small button at the right bottom corner this small button at the left side of „overlays“ and on this button there are two spheres

Your problem was that you unchecked overlays so you can‘t see the wireframe of the object

Answer (score 1):

I nearly had the same problem, i couldnt see any vertices i selected. The solution was to go to the viewport shading panel and check the backface culling in the options.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add I had a problem with this too but the solution for me was different from anything anyone else has said. To fix it for me, I had to change the OFFSET of the SOLIDIFY modifier to a NEGATIVE value. When it is positive, I cannot see the vertices. Hope this is helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but none of these solutions worked, in my case the **selected mode** was set to **Edge select**, so the solution was simply return to the **Vertex select**, as shown in the image below, but anyways learned that there's a lot of ways to turn those vertices of, though.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realised that was editing a shapekey instead of selecting base shape.

Allways be sure you are editing the base shape not shape key.

Answer (score -1):

In my case in needed to deactivate and activate the *X-Ray* mode (squares, top right).