# vertex dots in edit mode disappered

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I've lost vertex dots in edit mode, is there any chance to bring them back?

[image]I have lost vertex dots in edit mode

Comment: Are you sure the widget is in vertex mode? It looks like edge mode that doesn't show verts.

Answer (score 2):

you are on edge mode, so either press the icon on top or number "1" on your keyboard (top).

[image]

Other reason why you may not see the vertices or any other element of your mesh highlighted may relate to this:

[Blender 2.8 I can't see vertices, edges or faces in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136154/blender-2-8-i-cant-see-vertices-edges-or-faces-in-edit-mode)

Comment: Oh, I was too slow editing the picture... Your answer is right :)

Answer (score 1):

You're in Edge Select Mode, you can see it at the top of the Editor window. Just click on the dot symbol left to the edge symbol.[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Cheers

Comment: You should mark both answers as correct or accepted :)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The user can only accept *one* answer as accepted.

Comment: I didn't know that, since I never got an answer to accept ;) Anyway, then he should choose one of them.