# Why did references, vertex dots, vertex lines, and ground lines disappear in blender

Tags: vertices

I probably mistapped a button to have this mode entered. How do I fix it back?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome. Top right of the 3D View,, the button in the header with 2 overlapping circles, > _Show Overlays_.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136154/blender-2-8-i-cant-see-vertices-edges-or-faces-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

press this button (show overlays) again

[image]

you can find it in the upper right corner of your 3d view.

[image]

Comment: Oh fuck new bie question. Might have pressed a key accidentally.