# Can't see all my vertices of selected object in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, subdivision-surface, solidify-modifier

I've tried looking up this issue and mainly come across [this result](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136154/blender-2-8-i-cant-see-vertices-edges-or-faces-in-edit-mode?newreg=e28ffa4aff804ab5ae72158fb0f37bc6), which doesn't resolve my issue as my overlays are turned on. I was following [this tutorial on YouTube by Blender Guru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1isb0x4zYw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=4), until I decided to take a break, save the file, close it, and reopen it, and now this issue occurred.

Basically, I'm only able to see some of the vertices of the donut icing in edit mode, and would like to see all of them when I select the icing, to have more flexibility when editing it.

In the Youtube video, as well I think before I closed and reopened it, all the vertices of the selected object seem to be visible in edit mode. However, I'm unable too see them all.

Any help to see the vertices so I can edit the icing more comfortably would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This was the correct answer and helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, the solution was apparently:

- Go to Modifier Properties (the wrench icon).
- Click the "On Cage" button (which is the triangle with the three dots) on the modifiers.

I guess I may have turned these off by accident or something at some point. But leaving this here in case anyone else encounters a similar issue.